# Swiftでのuint8_tのcastの方法がわかりません

Tags: objective-c, swift, bluetooth

```
uint8_t*    buf = (uint8_t*)[characteristic.value bytes];
_textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", buf[0]];
```

こちらのObjective-CのコードをSwiftで書きたいのですがうまく書く書き方がわかりません。
教えていただけると嬉しいです

Answer (score 2):

次のように書くか

```
var data = characteristic.value
var bytes = [UInt8](count:data.length, repeatedValue:0)
data.getBytes(&bytes, length:data.length)
textField.text = "\(bytes[0])"
```

または、下記のほうが元のObjective-Cのコードにより近いかもしれません。

```
var data = characteristic.value
let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(characteristic.value.bytes)
let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start:ptr, count:data.length)
textField.text = "\(bytes[0])"
```

Comment: `let buf = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(characteristic.value.bytes)`
で行けました！ありがとうございます！